# Bibilio module will not show saved authors (contributors) on the back or frontend

Tags: entities, theming

I've inherited a Drupal site that is using the Biblio module to save bibliographic records as nodes.

The Biblio module creates a fieldset for "Contributors," these are the authors of the item (books in this case). These contributors get saved to the database when the node is saved but do not show up in this Contributors fieldset on the back end and are not printed on the frontend - the other Biblio fields are printed except for the Contributors. I can not figure out with this is happening.

The site is on Drupal 7.43 with Biblio 7.x.-1.0-rc7 (this is the latest stable version of Biblio 1.0).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!